# Step by step pattern with data transfer between steps

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I write simple application which consists of several step. Each step takes its specified input data and produces its specified output. I try to realize such pattern based on pipeline pattern. There are common parts:
Interface that each step must realize:

```
interface IStep
{
    Data Execute(Data data);
}
```

Interface that must be implemented by class that processes steps:

```
interface IProcess
{
    void AddStep(IStep step);
    void Run();
}
class Process: IProcess
{
    private List<IStep> steps = new List<IStep>();

    public void AddStep(IStep step)
    {
        steps.Add(step);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var data = new Data();
        foreach(step in steps)
        {
            data = step.Ececute(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of Data class is the next:

```
public class Data: Dictionary<string, object> {}
```

And this is a problem. I have to store key constants for Data and in the beggining of each step extract values required by step. Is there more elegant way to implement such approach?

Comment: DataFlow is pretty much exactly what you are wanting to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library

Comment: Second vote for dataflow, there is a learning curve but its worth it

Comment: `Chain of responsibility` is another solution for this kind of scenario.